# Angular UI Bootstrap Carousel Pause

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, angular-ui-bootstrap

How to pause Angular UI Bootstrap Carousel. Also it'd be great if you provide something to reverse to carousel direction.
Here is the [link](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/carousel) to docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set **`interval`** attribute to -ve or 0 integer to pause the carousel

`<uib-carousel interval="-1">`

Obviously `interval` can be set with any data-bound variable with -ve or 0 as value

Comment: can i use something like interval='{{myValue}}'

Comment: you should use `interval="myValue"` without `{{ }}`